# Applying Angle Bisector Theorem

Tags: geometry

[image]

In the $\triangle ABC$, $[AD]$ and $[BE]$ are angle bisectors. Find the side $|BC|$

To apply the Angle Bisector Theorem, I need to know the side $|AB|$.

Regards!

EDIT: My attempt:

[image]

Comment: No need to downvote, just looking for some help. Does anyone have any idea?

Comment: Please show us how you have applied the angle bisector theorem.

Comment: @GNUSupporter As you wish :) I'm uploading a new diagram now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From $\triangle ABE$:
$$\frac{AB}{AE}=\frac{BD}{DE} \Rightarrow \frac{AB}{AE}=\frac{3}{2} \qquad (1)$$
From $\triangle ABC$:
$$\frac{AE}{CE}=\frac{AB}{BC} \Rightarrow \frac{AE}{6}=\frac{AB}{x} \qquad (2)$$
Now multiply $(1)$ and $(2)$:
$$\require{cancel}\frac{\cancel{AB}}{\bcancel{AE}}\cdot \frac{\bcancel{AE}}{6}=\frac{3}{2}\cdot \frac{\cancel{AB}}{x} \Rightarrow x=\frac{3}{2}\cdot 6=9.$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint. Note that the three interior angle bisectors of a triangle $\triangle ABC$ meet in a single point $D$ (the so-called [incenter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incenter)). Hence the segment $DC$ (draw it) is bisects the angle at $C$.

Now apply the [angle bisector theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angle_bisector_theorem) to the triangle $\triangle EBC$ with respect to the bisector at $DC$.

Comment: I didn't get your hint.

Comment: Apply the angle bisector theorem to the triangle $\triangle EBC$ with respect to the bisector at $DC$

Comment: There's no angle bisector at $DC$. I really don't know what am missing right now.

Comment: There is , since $AD$ and $BE$ intersect at $D$ and $DC$ is also a bisector since $D$ is the intersection point of two bisectors.

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner Then I need to draw a line from $D$ to $C$

Comment: Note that the three interior angle bisectors of any triangle meet in a single point. Hence if you draw $DC$ then you have the missing bisector.

Comment: @RobertZ am confused again

Comment: Read carefully https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angle_bisector_theorem
Then apply the angle bisector theorem to the triangle $\triangle EBC$ with respect to the bisector at $DC$.

Answer (score 0):

If $CE=6$ then $$\frac{x}{6}=\frac{3}{2}$$

Comment: I tried doing this.

Comment: How did you get that

Comment: Draw the line $DC$ and aply the angle bisector theorem at triangle $$\Delta BEC$$